# Solve for the domain of x

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

## Solve for the domain of x

---

$$y=\sqrt{\text{Cos}\left[x^2\right]}\tag1$$

my answer:where is wrong?

$\text{Cos}\left[x^2\right]\geq 0$, so $x^2\in [2k \pi -\pi /2,2k \pi +\pi /2]\Rightarrow x\in \left[\sqrt{2k \pi -\pi /2},\sqrt{2k \pi +\pi /2}\right]$

## The answer in my book

---

a little strange for me

$\text{Cos}\left[x^2\right]\geq 0$, so $0\leq x^2\leq \pi /2 \&\&(4k-1)\pi /2\leq x^2 \le (4k+1)\pi /2\quad (k=1,2,\dots)$

so, the domain is $|x|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\&\&(4k-1)\pi /2\leq |x|\leq \sqrt{(4k+1)\frac{\pi }{2}}\quad (k=1,2,\dots)$

Comment: Looks fine, except that the domain is the *union* of your sets, as $k$ ranges over the integers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas added one answer in my book. A little strange, maybe my answer omitted something?

Comment: Is it $\cos(x^2)$ or $\cos\lfloor x^2\rfloor $ with the floor function?

Comment: @julien $cos(x^2)$

Comment: @HyperGroups: Your answer (with union mentioned) is completely correct. The book answer expresses it differently. Instead of using your version, they concentrate first on the positives. So that's $0$ to $\sqrt{\pi/2}$, and then $\sqrt{(2k\pi-\pi/2}$  to $\sqrt{2k\pi+\pi/2}$ for all positive $k$. Then because of the symmetry of $\cos$ about the $y$-axis, taking absolute value takes care of the negatives. I think your version is a little "nicer" but the sets are the same.

Comment: @HyperGroups: I slipped, did not notice that you were taking square roots of negatives. You need to use absolute value for the cases where $2k\pi-\pi/2$ is negative.

Comment: @AndréNicolas good to know that people like you (strong) will slipped in such case, I'm not lonely. :)

Comment: @HyperGroups...We **all slip** (anyone who claims otherwise is **lying**) ;-)

Comment: Why do you write \text{Cos} instead of \cos?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I write in `Mathematica` and copy to here, sometimes it is convenient in plotting and striking in editing. If necessary I'll improve it in future. There is a shortcut for `[ ]` but no for `()`

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hi, I noticed your edit, I found the `\tag{12}` always in first line, Which is better for `(12)` in first line of a display formula or in the last line of a display formula?
Here is one display formula with multiple lines. 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433789/questions-about-summation-by-parts

Comment: @HyperGroups : I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy see the difference of these two `$$number~in~first~line\sum _{n=pn}\\Second~Line
\tag{1}$$`   `$$\sum _{n=p}\\Second~Line
~~~number~in~the~last~line~~~~~~~~(1)$$` The place of (1) are different.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh, after seeing your edit, I got it: After `aligned` then `\tag{1}` will at the end of the display formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning and results regarding $x^2$ are fine, and you conclusions about the domain of $x$ are understandable, but we want to cover the case of negative values of $x$, which we can't do using $k\lt 0$, because the radicand of the square-root function must be non-negative. But we can cover both negative and positive $x$-values to include in the domain by expressing the domain of $|x|$ as the **union** of all your intervals, but restricting $k$ the range of $k$ to the *positive integers*: ($k \leq 0$ gives one or more undefined intervals).

$$|x| \in\left[0, \sqrt{\pi/2}\right] \cup \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb Z^+} \left[\sqrt{2k \pi -\pi /2},\sqrt{2k \pi +\pi /2}\right]$$

I've explicitly written the interval we need to join, through union, to the "big" union, since it's not covered by any interval for which $k \geq 1$.

Comment: added one answer in my book. A little strange, maybe my answer omitted something?

Comment: We list the domain as the domain of |x|, which allows us to keep the radicands used in the intervals, the unions of which we are taking, non-negative, as did the solution in your text. Since we are taking only positive k in the Big sum, I included the interval which is part of the domain, but is not included in the union of the other intervals.

Comment: @amWhy: nice discourse ... +1