# questions about Rudin's summation by parts

Tags: alternative-proof, solution-verification

## rudin's summation by parts

---

3.41  Theorem Given two sequences $\left\{a_n\right\}$,$\left\{b_n\right\}$,put

$$\begin{align*}A_n=\sum _{k=0}^n a_k~~~(1)\end{align*}$$

if $n\geq 0$; put $A_{-1}=0$. Then, if $0\leq p\leq q$, we have

$$\begin{align*}\sum _{n=p}^q a_nb_n=\sum _{n=p}^{q-1} A_n\left(b_n-b_{n+1}\right)+\color{blue}{A_qb_q}\color{red}{-}\color{blue}{A_{p-1}b_p}.~~~(2)\end{align*}$$

[wiki's summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)

### My derivation:

---

blue color highlight the changed item.
[image]

### Questions

---

#### question1:

---

The blue part of (2) is a little hard to memorize before I've done the calculation.

What's the relation between (2) and the [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) which I think is easier to memorize (without those indexes).

$\int f dg=f g-\int f dg$

or

$\int _a^bF(x)g(x)dx=F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)-\int _a^bf(x)G(x)dx$

#### question2:

---

What's the guidelines to derive the (2)?

As you see the wiki's edition, there are also several versions.

Although I get (2), I did it by cheating, i.e. I'm doing proof, and I checked (2) in my process of derivation.

Of course, the proof in text, is much easier:

$$\begin{align*}\sum _{n=p}^q a_nb_n=\sum _{n=p}^q \left(A_n-A_{n-1}\right)b_n=\sum _{n=p}^q A_nb_n-\sum _{n=p-1}^{q-1} A_nb_{n+1}~~~(4)\end{align*}$$

,and the last expression on the right is clearly equal to the right side of (2)

#### question3

---

$A_n$is summation from $0$ to $n$, how does it look reasonable when $p=5$?

Comment: Any suggestions about latex and writings are also welcome, I'm novice in SE.

Comment: Yes, the calculation is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott hi, thanks for verification, I've added my further questions.

Comment: MathJax so slow and stuck when editing in SE.  Should I use image for large DisplayFormula.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define
$$
A_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\quad\text{and}\quad F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$

**Question 1:**

Consider summation by parts
$$
\sum_{k=m}^na_kb_k
=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)
$$
vs integration by parts
$$
\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)g(b)-F(a)g(a)-\int_a^bF(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
The parallel seems pretty clear.

---

**Question 2:**

I'm not sure what you mean by guidelines to derive summation by parts. Basically, summation by parts is just a change of the index of summation.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^na_kb_k
&=\sum_{k=m}^n(A_k-A_{k-1})b_k\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^nA_kb_k-\sum_{k=m}^nA_{k-1}b_k\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^nA_kb_k-\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}A_kb_{k+1}\\
&=A_nb_n+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_kb_k-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_kb_{k+1}\\
&=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})
\end{align}
$$

---

**Question 3:**

$$
\sum_{k=5}^na_kb_k
=A_nb_n-A_4b_5-\sum_{k=5}^{n-1}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)
$$
It looks reasonable to me. If you're worried about where the summation starts, that only alters $A_n$ by a constant. Consider how much a constant added to $A_n$ changes the value of the summation by parts formula:
$$
\begin{align}
&(A_n+C)b_n-(A_{m-1}+C)b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(A_k+C)(b_{k+1}-b_k)\\
&=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)\\
&+C\left(b_n-b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(b_{k+1}-b_k)\right)\\
&=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)\\
&+C(b_n-b_m-(b_n-b_m))\\
&=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)
\end{align}
$$
$C$ has no effect on the final value of the formula.

Comment: Ah, your form is much better parallel to integration by parts. 

Why your $A_n=\sum _{k=1}^n a_k$, not $A_n=\sum _{k=0}^n a_k$?

Comment: @HyperGroups: as I showed in my answer to Question 3, it doesn't matter where you start the summation for $A_n$.

Comment: got it, thanks. $\sum _{k=m}^n a_kb_k=A_nb_n-A_{\color{red}{m}}b_m-\sum _{k=m}^{\color{red}{n}} A_k\left(b_{k+1}-b_k\right)$if without calculation, maybe I'll write some indexes wrongly when recall this formula like this, do you think it's more perfect? of course its wrong....

Comment: The guidelines mean some rules when changing of index of summation. Sometimes I feel it hard to choose which change is the fastest, most efficient, and needed, and when to stop.
For example, this is one rule,$\sum _{k=m}^n A_{k-1}b_k$, here I wanna make $A_{k-1}$ becomes $A_k$, so I change to $\sum _{k=m-1}^{n-1} A_kb_{k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks @robjohn for the nice and simple derivations :-)